# What does the `free` method from TProcess do?

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

What does the `free` method do in `TProcess`. It's used in several examples I found on the net but there's nothing in the [reference](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/fcl/process/tprocess.html) about it? So far I used it and everything works fine. Can I continue to use it or should I use a different method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the `Free` method defined in `TObject`, at the very root of the class hierarchy. This method does the same thing in every single class, there is nothing special with `TProcess` in this regard.

It is [documented](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/tobject.free.html):

> `Free` will check the `Self` pointer and calls `Destroy` if it is different from `Nil`. This is a safer method than calling `Destroy` directly.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Fair point, that text is not relevant to this answer, and if we remove it then we can avoid rekindling FAN wars. Which I did. We can tidy up these comments now.